# Android-Alert Dialog not working

Tags: android

For some reason, I can not get this dialog to show up on the screen. It is triggered by a button press which I know works but the dialog doesn't launch, why not?

```
     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SummaryActivity.this);
      builder.setTitle(R.string.please_confirm)
             .setMessage(R.string.terms_details)
             .setCancelable(false)
             .setPositiveButton(R.string.sign_to_agree, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {        
                    Intent DrawIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DrawingActivity.class);
                    startActivity(DrawIntent);
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_button_label, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
               }
           });
     AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add

```
alert.show();
```

after

```
 AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

this code then u r dialog will be shown on screen.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```
alert.show();
```

at the end to actually get it on screen

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to display your dialog alert, use `show()` of *AlertDialog* 
 add this to end of your code `alert.show();`

Comment: why downvote? whats wrong with answer?better explain the reason instead crudely downvoting the answer.